# create-react-app command not making proper app

Tags: reactjs

[see last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvTHo.png)this command "create-react-app axixa" not executing

Creating a new React app in D:\react\axixa.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall D:\react\axixa\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall D:\react\axixa\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

- react-scripts@3.0.1
- react@16.8.6
- react-dom@16.8.6
  added 1386 packages from 675 contributors in 1430.348s
  "

happy hacking!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details as your question at the moment is difficult to answer. Why is it not making a proper app for you? Is the text in your question not the output from the command that you ran? Do you get an error message? Have you tried running the app after you created it?

Comment: i didn't get any error but the command is still not executing

Comment: @ÂnkitáSêthiã Which command is not executing?

Comment: @AdityaSrivast this command create-react-app axixa

Comment: Do you not get any output from the command? If you don't get any error then the command *should have executed*, otherwise your terminal would display an error. What do you mean when you type "not executing"; please expand on that

Comment: @ÂnkitáSêthiã I think the command has executed successfully. Try running `npm start`. It should display the custom react page on `localshost:3000`

Comment: @Patrick when i wrote that command in command prompt then Anti-malware not letting to execute this command and command stop working

Comment: @AdityaSrivast i already done